# Mysql query is not returning articles with no likes or no comments

Tags: mysql

Before downvoting, have a look at my question.

I am working on my article website. There is a section on my website where popular articles are shown. The popular articles are based on likes and comments. I am using below query to show popular articles:

```
select 
    s.id as story_id,
    s.title as story_title,
    COUNT(l.id) as total_likes,
    COUNT(cm.id) as total_comments
from
    stories s
right outer join 
    likes l
on 
    s.id = l.type_id
right outer join
    comments cm
on 
    cm.story_id = s.id

group by s.id

order by total_likes desc,total_comments desc
```

I am receiving the popular articles but only 5.The articles are showing but there are only 5, I want articles with no likes or comments after the last one Here is a screenshot

[image]

Here you can observe that the only articles are shown up who have at least 1 like or comment. I want to get articles with no likes or comments too

Can anyone solve my problem, Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return also the stories without likes or comments (you should use left join):

```
  select 
      s.id as story_id,
      s.title as story_title,
      COUNT(l.id) as total_likes,
      COUNT(cm.id) as total_comments
  from stories s
  left  join  likes l on  s.id = l.type_id
  left  join comments cm on  cm.story_id = s.id

  group by s.id, s.title
  order by total_likes desc,total_comments desc
```

Answer (score 2):

You've to use left join for this. This should work:

```
 select 
      s.*,
      COUNT(l.id) as total_likes,
      COUNT(cm.id) as total_comments
  from stories articles
  left  join  likes l on  articles.id = l.type_id
  left  join comments cm on  cm.story_id = s.id

  group by articles.id, articles.title
  order by total_likes desc,total_comments desc
```

Hope it helps